# can I get an observable value synchronically? (Angular/ReactiveX)

Tags: angularjs, angular, reactivex

I have an boolean observable in my project that called `isPossible`, this is how it declared:

```
  isPossible: Observable<boolean>;
```

I want to add condition that this is `isPossible` is `true`, but I want to add it to a place where other conditions are evaluate synchronically, the only way i know how to use the value of observable is with async pipe...like `{{isPossible | async}}`, but here I need to get it synchronically...how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of Observable as a kind of Promise which can return more than one value over time. In this case you're creating asynchronous stream which is emitting boolean values. The way you can react to the values is to put your action on `subscribe` of the stream and then you get the real value:

```
isPossible.subscribe((latestIsPossibleValue: boolean) => {
  if (latestIsPossibleValue) {
    // do something on 'true'
  }
})
```

Could you please expand more on the case you've got?

Comment: Instead of using `if (latestIsPossibleValue)` inside subscribe, i would use `.filter((latestIsPossibleValue: boolean) => latestIsPossibleValue)` before subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the async when you want sync

```
{{isPossible}}
```

and eventually don't make it Observable, just a simple boolean

Comment: It have to be Observable for other places im using it, just for this case I want to get the value synchronically

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `isPossible.filter(e => e).subscribe((e) => { ... })`.

In Rx, you first transform observables into other observables, for example in this case we change the isPossible observable that yields both `true` and `false`, into one that only yields on `true` with `.filter(e => e)`.

Next, you can subscribe to the observable. `subscribe` activates the observable sequence. Once subscribed, the code inside subscribe will execute each time a value is yielded.